# EJB MDB migration from 2.1 to version suitable for JavaEE6

Tags: spring, java-ee-6, ejb-2.x

I need bit of the help before i start analyzing the migration of EJB 2.1.
we are using ejb2.1 version. Which is the appropriate ejb version for javaEE6?
what impact will happen on spring from ejb migration? as we are using spring dependency injection for integrating with Message driven beans.
Any good migration guide from ejb2.1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you actually need to continue support of Spring+EJB?  Might be better to jump into pure Spring, with its implementation of MDBs. This will simplify everything dramatically, in my opinion. I have migrated JEE5+JSF1.2+Seam2.2 (and yes, have been using MDBs there with "Seam injection") to pure recent Spring + Spring boot (and other spring-based tools) and have found all this much more efficient to work.

Comment: Hi IIya, Thanks for the reply. Yes this is the requirement that i got. we are not in a position to move completely to spring as of now. So any answers to my questions.

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with EJB 2.1, I would leave everything as-is.  It's not "deprecated", and things didn't change substantially for MDBs.  If you want to move to annotations, it's mostly just a matter of translating the `<message-driven>` XML elements to `@MessageDriven` annotation elements (and `@Resource`, `@EJB`, etc. as needed).  If you have a more specific question, you will likely get a more specific answer.

Comment: Hi Brett, Thanks for you information. But still we would like to migrate to newer version of ejb to make use of its new features during enhancements. So on more specific question.  which newer version of ebj is appropriate for javaee6? any good migration material for ebj2.1 to newer version?can i use annotation based spring dependency for integrating MDBs?

Comment: EJB 3.1 is correct for JEE6